# Jenkins check if env.BRANCH_NAME contains some keyword in Post Section

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to skip certain branches which contain "HotFix" as a word. Is it possible to have something like below in the Jenkins file?

```
post {
    success {
        withCredentials(some_details) {
            script {
                try {
                    if (!env.BRANCH_NAME.contains('HotFix')) {

                    }
                    else {

                    }
                }
                catch (err) {
                    echo    err
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jenkins Declarative pipeline supports [`when` directive](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) that can skip certain stages based on predefined conditions. Consider the following example:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("A") {
            steps {
                // ....
            }
        }

        stage("B") {
            when {
                expression {
                    !env.BRANCH_NAME.contains("HotFix")
                }
            }
            steps {
                // ....
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, we want to execute stage `B` only if the current branch name does not contain `HotFix`.

Comment: How do I write in Post event? I have all the stages already run and I need to check the branch name in the post event.

Comment: @Shubh Please explain more clearly in your question what you are trying to achieve. Your question started with a sentence _"I need to skip certain branches which contain "HotFix" as a word."_ and this is what `when` directive is designed for - to skip certain branches based on a condition. I don't know what post actions have to do with it. Please rephrase your question and explain more clearly your expectations so we can provide you a more accurate answer.